# Fully encrypted system boots to Terminal login instead of GUI

Tags: login, lightdm, tty, dbus

When I switch on computer, because I have it encrypted, it always first asks for my passphrase in the GUI. I enter the phrase, then still in the GUI it normally asks for my password, and goes to the GUI desktop.

Now, for some reason, it started going direct to Terminal after I enter the passphrase, with the prompt:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS thomas-All-Series tty1
thomas-All-series login:
```

I don't know why this started.

After logging in as user (not root), the following pieces of information spew out:

```
Last login: Sat Jan 9 18:23:13 CST 2016 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: https://helpubuntu.com
find: '/var/lib/apt//lists/': No such file or directory
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available: 39: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/updates available: Directory nonexistent
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/updates available: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 1
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 39: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Directory nonexistent
/usr/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Directory nonexistent
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
thomas@thomas-All-Series:~$ _
```

I tried `startx $(which unity)` in both my username and root to see if there was a difference, and this is the readout I got in both:

```
(compiz:1347): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf:
Cannot spawn a message bus without a machine-id:
Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id or /etc/machine-id:
Failed to open file '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': No such file or directory
```

The above message is repeated three times, followed by:

```
WARN 2016-01-13 20:06:08 unity.glib.dbus.server GlibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't registe
r object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2016-01-13 20:06:09 unity.debug.interface DebugBusInterface.ccp:216 Unable to
load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object
file: No such file or directory
process 1347: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up: failed to read machine
uuid: Failed to open "/etc/machine-id": No such file or directory
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
ERROR 2016-01-13 20:06:09 unity.launcher.entry.remote.mode1 LauncherEntryRemoteMode1
.cpp:50 Unable to connect to session bus: Cannot spawn a message bus without a machi
ne-id: Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id or /etc/machine-id: Failed to open fi
le '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': No such file or directory
CRIT 2016-01-13 20:06:09 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to get org.ayatana.bamf matcher: 
Cannot spawn a message bus without a machine-id: Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machin
e-id or /etc/machine-id: Failed to open file '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': No such fil
e or directory
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing l
og file.
```

Comment: Wait a while. If after about a minute still nothing happens, press CTRL+ALT+F7. You should see the LightDM log-in screen. If you have no luck and the screen stays black, go back with CTRL+ALT+F1. Then enter your user name (not the display name! It's the one without spaces and only lowercase alphanumeric characters.). After that it will ask for your password. Enter it and don't worry that you don't see any echo characters as you type. Then you should have a console login. You can start the Unity desktop environment using `startx $(which unity)`. This is not a solution but a temporary workaround

Comment: You see any interesting error messages in the terminal? And you could try a `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` when logged into the console and then try the startx thing again or reboot. If that doesn't help, maybe reading through the question over there might be a good idea: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: Or does any related error show up in `dmesg`

Comment: @Push If you have new interesting outputs or other information, please [edit] your question to provide it! Use code formatting (CTRL+K or the **`{}`**-button) if necessary. Then write a short comment to notify the people waiting for your reaction. If you post important information in comments, it does not only lose every formatting and becomes incredibly hard to read, comments also may get deleted for several reasons without any warning.

Comment: @ByteCommander i took your advice and edited the question. above you can see the two outputs I get when i login and when i type `startx $(which unity)`

Comment: @ByteCommander when i type `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` as root, it spits out:
`chown: missing operand after 'root':~ 
Try 'chown --help' for more information.`

Comment: @Push You missed the space between the colon and the tilde. It's `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` and *not* `sudo chown -R $USER:~`. But my knowledge is not enough to help you any more than that... No idea about those messages. I'm sorry.

Comment: @ByteCommander No, I got the space... nothing happens. Among other problems I've found... I cannot install anything. It just says `unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)` Something is seriously screwed up with my OS.

Comment: The `chown` command I gave you exited successfully if it doesn't say anything. Actually most Linux commands and programs print nothing to the terminal if they succeed. It's a convention to only notify the user on errors. And the second one is a common "problem" which you can find easily on this site. For example http://askubuntu.com/q/15433/367990 tells you how to solve this. Usually this error just means that another package manager (or updater) is currently running. Exit the other one or reboot if you can't find it and then try again..